# What can I do with leftover almond pulp?

Tags: culinary-uses, almonds

After making almond milk, I'm left with almond pulp that is flavourless. How can I use it instead of throwing it out?

Comment: did you consider compost?

Comment: I wonder if you could dry it out for almond flour?

Comment: Why was this closed?  The off-topic criteria specifically says : "Exceptions are made for items which are not generally considered to have any culinary use"